# How to remove content background from under Navigation Menu ( + below gadgets)

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm creating a very specific website design that I hope will turn out like this: http://prntscr.com/298r2m Problem is, coding isn't one of my strong points.

What I've got so far is this: http://prntscr.com/29i0ed and as you can see, the content background is under the Navigation menu and below image. I was wondering how to change that so that it ONLY starts at the point where the posts begin like in the picture above?

Also, does anyone know how to add a top and bottom border to the content background, instead of it looking like it's been cut off? I use blogger.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If I did, you just have two elements to the image and the body of your blog and being elements with different colors, I hope it helped you